# jolt transformation to remove key if value is not present

Tags: json, jolt

I have an input json in the form of key, value pair.
I don't want to include the key in the output if value for that key is missing. As in this input
teacherid is missing, so it shouldn't be included in the ouput.

**input** :

```json
{
  "alldetails": {
    "classid": 1,
    "schoolid": 3
  }
}
```

**jolt spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "alldetails": {
        "#Id_class": "data[0].source",
        "classid": "data[0].value",
        "#Id_teacher": "data[1].source",
        "teacherid": "data[1].value",
        "#Id_school": "data[2].source",
        "schoolid": "data[2].value"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**current output** :

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "source": "Id_class",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "Id_teacher"
    },
    {
      "source": "Id_school",
      "value": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

**desired output** :

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "source": "Id_class",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "Id_school",
      "value": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception runs on v0.1.1 which is old and don't support all features so created new on v0.1.6
https://vishavjeet6.github.io/jolt-transformer/

This worked for me

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "alldetails": {
        "classid": {
          "#Id_class": "data[0].source",
          "@(1,classid)": "data[0].value"
        },
        "teacherid": {
          "#Id_teacher": "data[1].source",
          "@(1,teacherid)": "data[1].value"
        },
        "schoolid": {
          "#Id_school": "data[2].source",
          "@(1,schoolid)": "data[2].value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to hardcode but a **shift** transformation in the following case will handle the issue without prefixing the values with **`Id_`**, and to do this apply a **modify-overwrite** transformation such as

```json
[
  { // generating sub-objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "alldetails": {
        "*id": {
          "*": {
            "@1": "data[#3].value",
            "$(1,1)": "data[#3].source" // replicates the values represented by asterisk 
                                        // located within "*id" after going two levels up
                                        // the tree counting by 0,1, eg. $(1, )
                                        // and pick the first asterisk, eg. $( ,1)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // prefixing the values for the sources attributes
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "s*": "=concat('Id_',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the input already is not got to do with **`teacher`**

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Edit : Based on your need, you might construct the transformation starting from an input which's preety similar to yours such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "alldetails": {
        "#Id_class": "[0].source",
        "classid": "[0].value",
        "#Id_teacher": "[1].source",
        "teacherid": "[1].value",
        "#Id_school": "[2].source",
        "schoolid": "[2].value"
      }
    }
  },
  { // add "value" attributes with a specific value(ToBeDeleted) if those don't exist currently per each object
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "~value": "ToBeDeleted"
      }
    }
  },
  { // set names for the objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@(1,value).&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // conditionally pick the objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ToBeDeleted": {
        "": "&"
      },
      "*": {
        "@": "data[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but the field name needs to be hardcoded, as I have shared a sample data, not all the source follows naming convention ID_

Comment: OK @Vishavjeet I've added the case.

Comment: I have added another answer. Isn't that a good short way? Can't test on demo site as its uses v0.1.1 its working fine with v0.1.6

Comment: @Vishavjeet Is input exactly same ? Then, I had already solved by two different methods exactly one month ago :), besides the first one is dynamic.